# Applet exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, html, applet

I have a folder with two files inside; the java .class file and the .html file. In my html file I call the .class file as an applet but it sais an error on the website its published to saying it can't find the .class file. This puzzles me since they are in the same directory and I triple checked for spelling errors.

Here is my .html file...

```
<html>

<head>
<title>Applet</title>
</head>

<body>
Program<br />
<applet code="testing.class" width="300" height="300"/>
</body>

</html>
```

and here is my .class file...

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;


public class testing extends java.applet.Applet{

    public void init(){

    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.drawOval(0,0,250,100);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.drawString("My Applet",10,50);
    }

}
```

My .class file is "testing.class" and my html file is "testingpage.html"

Here is the Full Entire error

```
load: class testing.class not found.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: testing.class
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Applet2ClassLoader.java:252)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Plugin2ClassLoader.java:249)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Plugin2ClassLoader.java:179)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Plugin2ClassLoader.java:160)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Plugin2ClassLoader.java:690)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.createApplet(Plugin2Manager.java:3045)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Plugin2Manager.java:1497)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: testing.class
load: class testing.class not found.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: testing.class
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Applet2ClassLoader.java:252)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Plugin2ClassLoader.java:249)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Plugin2ClassLoader.java:179)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Plugin2ClassLoader.java:160)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Plugin2ClassLoader.java:690)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.createApplet(Plugin2Manager.java:3045)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Plugin2Manager.java:1497)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: testing.class
```

Comment: @MarkByers it's more than likely a slip while typing as he refers to it as an `.html` file beforehand.

Comment: Yea I just edited my post. it looked weird cuz I was messing around with it before I asked and forgot to change it back

Comment: yea sorry about the mixup I just fixed it ;)

Comment: The code attribute should not have `.class` appended.  The `applet` element was never intended to be self-closed.  Can you put the HTML and class file at an URL somewhere so that we can see it fail?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `applet` tag should be:

```
<applet code=testing.class width="300" height="300" />
```

Notice the change in the `code` attribute. Compare to the example code listed in the [relevant Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/plugin/developer_guide/using_tags.html#applet):

```
<applet code=Applet1.class width="200" height="200">
Your browser does not support the <code>applet</code> tag.
</applet>
```

The following is working for me.

http://puu.sh/PebS

## TestingApplet.java

```
import java.applet.Applet;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public final class TestingApplet extends Applet {

  public void paint(final Graphics g){
    g.drawOval(0, 0, 250, 100);
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.drawString("My Applet", 10, 50);
  }
}
```

## testing-applet.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Applet</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    Program <br />
    <applet code=TestingApplet.class width="300" height="300" />
  </body>
</html>
```

If this is not working, I have two questions for you...

- Did you save the Java as a `.java` file and compile it to produce the correct `.class` file?
- Did you verify your browser is not caching an old incorrect version of the `.html` file?
- Are your `.class` and `.html` files in the same directory?

Comment: @user1500134 try without the quotes around the `code` attribute value.

Comment: It is working fine for me; see [this screenshot](http://puu.sh/PebS).
The Java code is [here](http://pastie.org/private/rk4ptks8f73nk1gtfdt4q) and the HTML [here](http://pastie.org/private/uxmu16pzycudgrnzruqba).

Make sure your browser is not caching the old HTML file.

Comment: Did you save the Java as a `.java` file and compile it to produce the correct `.class` file? Did you verify your browser is not caching an old incorrect version of the HTML file?

Comment: Hmmm, I closed my browser and reloaded the page but still isn't working... My current code looks identical to yours (except the file name(s)) so idk... i'll keep investigating

Comment: I compiled the .java and went to my eclipse workspace and took the .class version from the "bin" folder

Comment: Is your `.class` file in the same directory as your `.html` file?

Comment: This conversation is diverging from the topic, but I use [puush](http://puush.me/).

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that you're not openning the correct HTML file. **Use your File Browser** (Finder I guess ;) ) and look for the file in the Netbeans project directory. It should be in /build/classes/.html